# how do I use a smart card as KeyStore for client authentication during SSL/TLS?

Tags: authentication, ssl, client, pkcs#11

have been attempting to use a PKCS#11 token (Smart card) as a KeyStore (not the TrustStore) on the client side for client authentication of a TLS connection. However, the SSL handshake fails with a `SSLException` with the message:

> Unexpectedly, privatekey is not an RSA private key.

This cannot be true because the private key/certificate pairs on the smart card are RSA keys. Am I missing some configuration to use a smart card as a KeyStore for JSSE?

Here are my configuration details:

Firstly, configured the Sun PKCS#11 Provider to work with an 'ActivCard' dll that interfaces with the smart card. The Sun PKCS#11 Provider configuration file just contains the 'name' and 'library' attributes.

The instantiation of the SunPKCS#11 provider looks like this:

```
java.security.AuthProvider provider = 
    new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.SunPKCS11(<Configuration file>);
```

Then, the instantiation of a `java.security.KeyStore` object from the smart card is done using this code below:

```
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter thePasswordProtection = 
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection( null );

KeyStore.Builder theBuilder = 
    KeyStore.Builder.newInstance( "PKCS11", provider, thePasswordProtection );

java.security.KeyStore theKeyStore = theBuilder.getKeyStore();
```

Moreover, this instantiated `KeyStore` is used to make a `KeyManagerFactory` to be used by JSSE using the code below:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.
    getInstance( "SunX509", "SunJSSE" );

kmf.init( theKeyStore, <smart card pin> );
```

This KeyManagerFactory is used to then initialize an SSLContext which is then used to instantiate an SSLSocket.

As per instructions in [Oracle's JSSERefGuide for Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#PKCS11), this is all I need to do for it to work. Although it is not required to set the below system properties while using the keystores programmatically, I also tried adding the system properties:

- `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` to `PKCS11`,
- `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` to `NONE` and
- `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider` to the name specified for the Sun PKCS#11 provider in its configuration file.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Any pointers or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am using RSA'S SSL/TLS provider for the SSL/TLS itself and not the default SunJSSE implementation, if that is relevant at all.

Comment: Surely you have to call `Security.addProvider()` somewhere along the line, with the `new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.SunPKCS11()`?

Comment: Yes EJP, I did add it to the list of providers. Sorry, I forgot to include that detail. Also, the SunPKCS11 provider does give me a KeyStore just fine and I can tell it is of type PKCS11 with all the keys in there. I even get as far as to pass on that KeyStore to the KeyManagerFactory to do SSL. But the SSL handshake fails.

Comment: Just noticed this is similar to my issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977268/java-ssl-client-not-selecting-a-smartcard-key

Any solution here?